# Inserting string in file in nth line after pattern using sed

Tags: linux, sed, insert, match, line

I want to insert word after nth line after pattern using sed.
I tied to modify this command but it inserts only in first line after pattern.

```
sed -i '/myPattern/a \ LineIWantToinser ' myFile
```

What command should I use to insert for example in third line after pattern?

Comment: You want the Nth line after the line with that pattern? Or the line after the Nth line with that pattern? Or the Nth line after the Nth line with that pattern? Whichever case you want `sed` probably isn't the best tool for this. `awk` might be easier (though you should be able to do some of those with `sed` easily enough).

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do it with GNU sed is.. (maybe some direct solution exists!?)

```
sed -n '/pattern/=' file
```

to see line where pattern is (grep also can be used here with -n)

then if linenumber+ numoflines is for example 123

```
sed '123aSOME INSERTED TEXT AFTER THAT LINE' file
```

where little a is append command (after that line, if i is used will be pre pattern line)

ps. I'm eager to see if @neronlevelu (or other sed Lover) will find some better sed solution.

Edit: i've found it, it seems a for append or i for insert must? be on first position on line when using { with ; inside } like

```
sed '/pattern/{N;N;N;
a  SOME TEXT FOR INSERTING
}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/pattern/{N;N;N;i \
Line to add after 3 lines with patterne as starting counter
}' YourFile
```

- number of `N` to add line between pattern and inserted line.
- there is no check for end of file or pattern in the 3 lines. (not specified in PO)

Comment: getting error of unmatched "{" as the closing "}" is not present

Answer (score 0):

A version with `bash` and `ed`:

```
ed -s myFile <<<$'/myPattern/+3a\n LineIWantToinser \n.\nwq'
```

`ed` enables us to use the line addressing `/myPattern/+3`.